# Bootstrap max height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The contents of my website are not displayed correctly. I have already tried in my css file, but without success.
Here is an excerpt from my styles.css.
Thanks for the help

```
    * {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
   }

   /* Body */
   body {
    position: relative;
    margin: 30px 0 100px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .navbar-fixed-top {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: max height is not working

Comment: Kindly explain _properly_. Please tell how it is being displayed and how do you want it to be.

Comment: The page is not displayed until the end. If something is more than half the page displayed can not be scrolled further down. The rest of page content is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it this way:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

It should work, if I understood what you are trying to do.

Comment: please take a look[link](https://ssl.webpack.de/dev-homepage.kwp-klein.com/de/rechtliche-hinweise.php)

Comment: Do you want the header to scroll with the page? Or to keep it visible at all times?

Comment: The header and the footer are fixed. Please take a look. [link](https://ssl.webpack.de/dev-homepage.kwp-klein.com/de/rechtliche-hinweise.php)

Answer (score 0):

If i iunderstand correct when you scroll down to the bottom of the page the footer is covering part of the content. So what you need to do is either with jquery get the height of footer and apply it as margin-botton to the content... or set max-height to footer and set that max-height value as margin botton to the content